# Bash script not recognizing existing file

Tags: bash, oracle, file-exists

I have to write a simple bash script, which does the compilation of multiple sql scripts which can contain recursive references to the other sql scripts with [Oracle SQLPlus convention](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12003.htm#BACIEHDJ), so in the end the result will be only one SQL file, containing all statements from all (possibly also recursively) referenced subscripts.

I have created a simple script called oracle-script-compressor.sh with following bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
function err () {
    echo $* > "/dev/stderr"
}


function replace_subscripts_placeholders() {
    local PROCESSING_FILENAME=$1
    echo "-- processing file $PROCESSING_FILENAME"
    while read script_line; do
        local script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE="$(echo -e "${script_line}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')"
        if  [[ $script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE == \@\@* ]] ; then
            local file_name="./${script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE#\@\@}"
            echo "-- found reference to file $file_name"
            echo "-- starting with processing, pwd=$PWD"
            # for debug purposes:
            ls -la
            # but this returns always false:
            if [ -f "$file_name" ]; then
                # so this part is never started:
                . replace_subscripts_placeholders $file_name
            else
                err_msg="WARNING: Could not find the referenced file $file_name"
                echo "-- $err_msg"
                err $err_msg
            fi          
        else
            echo "$script_line"
        fi
    done < $PROCESSING_FILENAME 
}

if test -z "$1" ; then
    err "Usage: oracle-script-compressor.sh {file_name_to_process} [> output_file]"
    err "  Be aware, if the referenced files within {file_name_to_process} are not specified by absolute paths, you have to start the script from corresponding directory."
    err "  If the part [> output_file] is omitted, then this script writes to standard output"
    err "  If the part [>> output_file] is used, then the result will be appended to output_file it it exists before the processing"
else
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        replace_subscripts_placeholders $1
    else
        echo "file $1 does not exist"
    fi
fi
```

and I am stuck on interesting problem - it seems, inside of the function replace_subscripts_placeholders() the file check

```
        if [ -f "$file_name" ]; then
            . replace_subscripts_placeholders $file_name
        else
            err_msg="WARNING: Could not find the referenced file $file_name"
            echo "-- $err_msg"
            err $err_msg
        fi
```

never goes to the recursion call and even, if I remove the if statement and really call the function in recursion with the correct referenced file name, which exists, it is still not recognized to be found and not passed into the loop over all lines of the referenced file in the recursive call (then the error file not found comes and the loop cannot be executed).

I have added the debug messages into script like mentioned above in the script, but still I am unable to find, why the hell should bash not find the file, if it is in the same directory. The scripts are placed in

```
user@mycomputer:/tmp/test$ ls -la
celkem 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user  4096 zář 14 21:47 .
drwxrwxrwt 38 root     root     36864 zář 14 21:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 a.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 b.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   590 zář 14 21:46 start.sql
user@mycomputer:/tmp/test$
```

and the content of the file start.sql looks like this:

```
spool output__UpdSch.log
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode 
--
--
PROMPT a.sql - starting
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as START_TIMESTAMP from dual;
@@a.sql
PROMPT a.sql - finished
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as FINISH_TIMESTAMP from dual;
--
--
PROMPT b.sql - starting
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as START_TIMESTAMP from dual;
@@b.sql
PROMPT b.sql - finished
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as FINISH_TIMESTAMP from dual;
--
--
spool off
```

and if I execute the script, it seems it decoded the filenames correctly, but there is still the problem in bash - the testing of the file existence returns always false:

```
user@mycomputer:/tmp/test$ ~/tmp/oracle-script-compressor.sh start.sql 
-- processing file start.sql
spool output__UpdSch.log
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode 
--
--
PROMPT a.sql - starting
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as START_TIMESTAMP from dual;
-- found reference to file ./a.sql
-- starting with processing, pwd=/tmp/test
celkem 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user  4096 zář 14 21:47 .
drwxrwxrwt 38 root     root     36864 zář 14 21:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 a.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 b.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   590 zář 14 21:46 start.sql
-- WARNING: Could not find the referenced file ./a.sql
WARNING: Could not find the referenced file ./a.sql
PROMPT a.sql - finished
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as FINISH_TIMESTAMP from dual;
--
--
PROMPT b.sql - starting
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as START_TIMESTAMP from dual;
-- found reference to file ./b.sql
-- starting with processing, pwd=/tmp/test
celkem 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user  4096 zář 14 21:47 .
drwxrwxrwt 38 root     root     36864 zář 14 21:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 a.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    51 zář 14 21:45 b.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   590 zář 14 21:46 start.sql
-- WARNING: Could not find the referenced file ./b.sql
WARNING: Could not find the referenced file ./b.sql
PROMPT b.sql - finished
select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as FINISH_TIMESTAMP from dual;
--
--
spool off
user@mycomputer:/tmp/test$
```

The script has read access to files, everything is in the same folder, where I start the script, It also does not matter, if I reference the file with the current directory prefix "./" or not, it is just never found. Interesting is, the check during the start of the script passes correctly, the only problem is the searching within the function... I have also tried to call the function with preceded "." and without it, it makes no difference... There are also no trailing spaces in the referenced file names... It also makes no difference if I declare the variables inside of the function as local or not.
So I have no idea, what could be the problem, maybe I just looked too long on it and cannot see something - seems it has to be something trivial, like the function is started in some different current directory - (but pwd and ls shows the directory is always correct...???) - Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, you should read [ask] and more importantly [mcve].

Comment: I don't know about the `if` test (as @Nic3500 said, you really need to trim out everything that doesn't relate to the problem -- this is way to big and complicated for someone other than you to debug), but I do see one other problem: don't use the `.` command to run functions, that's not what it does. The `.` command runs commands *from script files* inline in the current shell (very similar to the `source` command). I'd also recommend putting `set -x` before the problem section to get an execution trace of what the shell is doing there.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanx for reply - the `.` was only the expression of despair :-). Of course I have tried it before without it too, it had no influence.

Comment: Generally my apologies - I thought, this example is minimal enough :-) The verbosity is caused by the debug messages, which are not important for the code, but can be helpful if reproducing the problem - I thought, everybody who would like to reproduce it would go in similar way. But thank you very much for the tip, I will try to produce something less verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments, it brought me to the solution. I found out, this problem was related to the fact, the test sql files were created on Windows, so they had in the end of line always the `<CR><LF>` characters. This leads to the fact in the original bash script I posted, the script line

`while read script_line`

puts into the variable not only the given file name from the line, preceded by the characters @@

`@@a.sql`

but also the `<CR>` character - in the variable is then the value

`@@a.sql<CR>`

what was the cause the file `a.sql` etc. could never be found. Of course the character  is invisible, so therefore it has not been shown on any debug echoing I made here - I had to put the content of `$file_name` between  some another characters and then i could see it in the echoed test... I made also some other corrections and the final working script looks in the following way, if somebody needs to join referenced SQL scripts into one, this does it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
function err () {
    echo $* > "/dev/stderr"
}


function replace_subscripts_placeholders() {
    local PROCESSING_FILENAME=$1
    echo "-- processing file $PROCESSING_FILENAME"
    while read script_line || [ -n "$script_line" ]; do
        local script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE="$(echo -e "${script_line}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | sed -e 's/^M$//')"
        if  [[ $script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE == \@\@* ]] ; then
            local file_name="${script_line_NO_LEAD_SPACE#\@\@}"
            echo "-- found reference to file $file_name"
            if [ -f "$file_name" ]; then
                replace_subscripts_placeholders $file_name
            else
                err_msg="WARNING: Could not find the referenced file $file_name"
                echo "-- $err_msg"
                err $err_msg
            fi          
        else
            echo "$script_line"
        fi
    done < $PROCESSING_FILENAME 
}

if test -z "$1" ; then
    err "Usage: oracle-script-compressor.sh {file_name_to_process} [> output_file]"
    err "  Be aware, if the referenced files within {file_name_to_process} are not specified by absolute paths, you have to start the script from corresponding directory."
    err "  If the part [> output_file] is omitted, then this script writes to standard output"
    err "  If the part [>> output_file] is used, then the result will be appended to output_file it it exists before the processing"
else
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        replace_subscripts_placeholders $1
    else
        echo "file $1 does not exist"
    fi
fi
```